# SSRS Alternating rows starting with same color in every group

Tags: reporting-services, colors, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to alternate row colors in SSRS but I want each group to start with the same color, independent of the amount of rows in the previous group. I know that the function =IIf(ROWNUMBER(NOTHING) MOD 2, "Transparent", "Gray") allows me to alternate the rows, but this creates

[image: Current colors alternating rows]

Which is not what I want, since group 2 now starts with a grey row. Below an example of the desired output where the first row in each group starts with a white background.

[image: Desired colors alternating rows]

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the scope that returns the row number

```
=IIF(ROWNUMBER("myRowGroupName") MOD 2, Nothing, "Gray")
```

`"MyRowGroupName"` is the name of the row group that you want to reset the colors, it is case sensitive and must be enclosed on double quotes.

All this does is evaluate `ROWNUMBER()` with in each group, so it will start at 1 again when it hits a new group.